# Problema con una función de una clase en C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

verán, estoy realizando un código para almacenar datos de pacientes en un hospital, un programa muy básico, estos datos se me guardaran en un fichero con el nombre que el usuario le indique, pero tengo un pequeño detalle con esta función

```
void mostrarINFO()
    {
        cout<<p;
        cout<<"Condicion: "<<condicion<<endl;
        cout<<h;
    }
```

esta clase esta función esta dentro de una clase hija de otra clase:
Esta es la clase padre que contiene esta funcion

```
class Almacenamiento
{
    public:
    virtual void mostrarINFO();
};
```

y esta es la clase hija que hereda esa función:

```
class Expedientes:public Almacenamiento
{
    Paciente p;
    Hospital h;
    char condicion[20];
    public:
    Expedientes(){};
    friend void operator>>(istream&ci, Expedientes *e)
    {
        cin>>e->h;
        cout<<"Estado del Paciente: ";
        cin>>e->condicion;
    }
    void mostrarINFO()
    {
        cout<<p;
        cout<<"Condicion: "<<condicion<<endl;
        cout<<h;
    }
};
```

anteriormente hay otras dos clases que toman los datos, tanto de los pacientes, como del hospital, para que comprendan mas, les adjuntare el codigo completo, bueno el datalle esta en que me tira un varios errores como lo son:*** 83 13      [Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'Paciente')***, entonces bien, intentando quitar esta funcion solo dejandolo asi, al compilar me tira el error: \collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status, pero por lo que tengo entendido, este error sale cuando el programa ya se esta ejecutando, pero en este caso no me aparece la consola, simplemente me tira ese error.

Acepto cualquier consejo, ayuda, de antemano gracias, adjunto el código completo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Clase donde se me mostrara los daros ingresados
class Almacenamiento
{
    public:
    virtual void mostrarINFO();
};

//Clase Paciente
class Paciente
{
    private:
    char n_Paciente[50];     //Nombres y Apellidos
    char c_identidad[30];    //Cedula de indentidad
    long n_Movil;            //Numero celular
    int edad;               //Edad de las personas

    public:                 //Metodos
    Paciente(){};
    void datosPaciente();
    friend void operator>>(istream&ci, Paciente &p)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Nombre del paciente: "; cin.getline(p.n_Paciente,50);
        cout<<"Cedula del paciente: ";cin.getline(p.c_identidad,30);
        cout<<"Numero de celular: ";cin>>p.n_Movil;
        cout<<"Edad del paciente: ";cin>>p.edad;
    }
    friend void operator<<(istream&ci, Paciente &p)
    {
        cout<<"Paciente: "<<p.n_Paciente;
        cout<<"Cedula: "<<p.c_identidad;
        cout<<"NÂ° Celular: "<<p.n_Movil;
        cout<<"Edad: "<<p.edad;
    }
};

//Clase Hospital
class Hospital
{
    private:        //Atributos
    int n_Sala;
    int t_Expediente;
    char t_Enfermedad [50];        
    public:
    Hospital(){};
    friend void operator>>(istream&ci, Hospital &h)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Numero de sala: ";cin>>h.n_Sala;
        cout<<"Tipo de expediente: ";cin>>h.t_Expediente;
        cout<<"Tipo de enfermedad: ";cin.getline(h.t_Enfermedad,50);
    }
    friend void operator<<(istream&ci, Hospital &h)
    {
        cout<<"Sala NÂ°: "<<h.n_Sala;
        cout<<"Tipo de Expediente: "<<h.t_Expediente;
        cout<<"Tipo de enfermedad: "<<h.t_Enfermedad;
    }
};

//Clase Expediente, hija de la clase Almacenamiento
class Expedientes:public Almacenamiento
{
    Paciente p;
    Hospital h;
    char condicion[20];
    public:
    Expedientes(){};
    friend void operator>>(istream&ci, Expedientes *e)
    {
        cin>>e->h;
        cout<<"Estado del Paciente: ";
        cin>>e->condicion;
    }
    /*void mostrarINFO()
    {
        cout<<p;
        cout<<"Condicion: "<<condicion<<endl;
        cout<<h;
    }*/
};
int Menu();

int main(void)
{
    Almacenamiento *Lista[40];
    int num=0;

    while (1)
    {
        int opc=Menu();
        
        if (opc==5) //Libera
        {
            for (int i=0;i<num;i++)
            {
                delete Lista[i];
            }
            break;
        }
        else if(opc==1) //Agrega Expediente
        {
            Expedientes *exp1=new Expedientes();
            cin>>exp1;
            Lista[num++]=exp1;
        }
        else if(opc==2) //Mira el expediente
        {
            for (int i=0;i<num;i++)
            {
                cout<<"Expediente "<<i+1<<":\n";
                Lista[i]->mostrarINFO();
            }
        }
        else if (opc==3)        //Graba el Expediente en un fichero
        {
            char nFichero[30];
            cout<<"Ingrese el nombrel del Fichero: ";cin>>nFichero;

            fstream fout(nFichero,ios::out|ios::binary);
            if (!fout)
            {
                cout<<"Error..."<<endl;
            }
            for (int i=0;i<num;i++)
            {
                fout.write((char *)Lista[i],sizeof(Expedientes));
                cout<<i<<"Datos Guardados en: "<<nFichero<<endl;
            }
            fout.close();
        }
        else if (opc==4)    //Carga un expediente
        {
            char nFichero[40];
            cout<<"Nombre del fichero: ";cin>>nFichero;
            fstream fin(nFichero,ios::in|ios::binary);
            if (!fin)
            {
                cout<<"No se puede abrir el fichero: "<<endl;
            }
            else 
            {
                int cont=0;
                while (true)
                {
                    Expedientes *exp1=new Expedientes();
                    Lista[num]=exp1;
                    if (!fin.read((char*)Lista[num],sizeof(Expedientes)))
                    {
                        delete exp1;
                        break;
                    }
                    num++;
                    cont++;
                    
                }
                cout<<cont<<"Datos cargados de "<<nFichero<<endl;
                
            }
        }
    }
    

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

int Menu()
{
    int opc;
    cout<<"\t\t** Registro de Expedientes **"<<endl;
    cout << "\t\t1. Agregar Expediente"<<endl;  
    cout << "\t\t2. Ver Expediente"<<endl;  
    cout << "\t\t3. Grabar Expediente"<<endl;  
    cout << "\t\t4. Cargar Expediente"<<endl;  
    cout << "\t\t5. Salir"<<endl;  
    cout << "\t\t\tOpc: ";    
    cin >> opc; 
    return opc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro y conciso pero tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> `no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'Paciente')`

> `no hay coincidencia para 'operator<<' (los tipos de los operandos son 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' y 'Paciente')`

El compilador te está avisando de que no se ha redactado el operador de inyección (`operator<<`) cuando a la izquierda hay un flujo de salida (`o`utput `stream`) y a la derecha hay un `Paciente`. Y es cierto ya que te has equivocado de tipos al redactar el operador:

```
friend void operator<<(istream&ci, Paciente &p)
//                     ^ <--- Esto es un flujo de entrada ('i'nput 'stream') no de salida!
{
    cout<<"Paciente: "<<p.n_Paciente;
    cout<<"Cedula: "<<p.c_identidad;
    cout<<"NÂ° Celular: "<<p.n_Movil;
    cout<<"Edad: "<<p.edad;
}
```

Seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream&o, const Paciente &p)
{
    return o <<"Paciente: "<<p.n_Paciente
             <<"Cedula: "<<p.c_identidad
             <<"NÂ° Celular: "<<p.n_Movil
             <<"Edad: "<<p.edad;
}
```

Los cambios que he hecho son:

1. La función de inyección devuelve una referencia al objeto de flujo de datos, para permitir encadenamientos del operador.
2. Se recibe el segundo parámetro como constante, ya que no va a ser modificado.
3. Devuelve en la función el objeto de flujo de datos, para permitir el encadenamiento del operador.

Por cierto, las funciones amigas se declaran dentro del objeto pero se definen fuera:

```
class Paciente
{
   ...
   // Declaración.
   friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&, const Paciente &);
   ...
}

// Definición.
ostream &operator<<(ostream&o, const Paciente &p)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: He solucionado el error, pero tengo ahora otra complicacion, al momento de guardar los datos en un archivo .txt por medio del fichero, ese solo me guarda las palabras y los numero me los muestra de esta manera: `œc@` o `3êW         `. pero me es curioso que al momento de exportar el archivo .txt al programa para poder visualizarlo por pantalla, todos los datos están como deberían de estar, adjuntare el código ya corregido.

Comment: No adjuntes el código corregido, si es un problema diferente redacta una nueva pregunta.